# Brown-Forsythe and Welch f-ratios in two-way ANOVAs?

Tags: anova, heteroscedasticity

I understand that in One-Way ANOVA two alternative F-Ratios have been derived to be robust when homogeneity of variance has been violated. Tomarkin and Serlin (1986) review amongst other techniques the Brown-Forsythe and Welch F-Ratios and conclude that both control the type I error rate well.

So far I have only come across W and B-Fs F Ratios in One-Way ANOVAS. Am I able to use them in ANOVAS with two factors? And if no, why not?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I found [this article by Algina & Olejnik (1984)](http://epm.sagepub.com/content/44/1/39.short).

The abstract:

> The Welch-James procedure may be used
>   to test hypotheses on means, when
>   independent samples from populations
>   with heterogeneous variances are
>   available. Until recently the
>   complexity of the available
>   presentations of this procedure
>   limited the application of this
>   procedure. To resolve this state of
>   affairs, summation formulas for the
>   Welch-James procedure are presented
>   for the 2 x 2 design. In addition,
>   matrix formulas that permit routine
>   application of the procedure to
>   crossed factorial designs are
>   presented.

It frankly looks a little hairy, but I thought it might be a start.

**Citation**

Algina, J., & Olejnik, S. F. (1984). Implementing the Welch-James procedure with factorial designs. *Educational and psychological measurement*, **44**(1), 39-48.

Comment: Looks like a great contribution to a topic that had many of us puzzled for a quite a while.

Answer (score 1):

The Brown-Forsythe F* can be used even in two-way ANOVAs. From what I can tell the F statistic is the same as for classic two-way ANOVA, the only difference is in how the degrees of freedom are calculated. Of course it gets more complicated for unbalanced factorial designs. (the original Brown & Forsythe's paper is available at http://www.jstor.org/stable/2529238)