# Welch's ANOVA with blocking

Tags: r, anova

My understanding is that Welch's ANOVA is often a good option for a one-way comparison of treatment groups where the assumption of homogeneity of variance between treatment groups is violated.

The implementations of Welch's ANOVA that I've found so far (in R) are all for a one-way comparison.

I found [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5346/brown-forsythe-and-welch-f-ratios-in-two-way-anovas) post, where one of the answers discusses factorial designs and Welch's ANOVA. So my understanding from this that it is theoretically possible to extend Welch's ANOVA beyond a one-way comparison...

1. Is it possible to implement a Welch's ANOVA with a treatment factor and a blocking factor, assuming that the blocking factor does not affect the variance?
2. Is this any simpler than doing this for a factorial design?
3. If yes to question 1, can anyone recommend an R package that is able to do this?
4. On the other hand, if you don't think that this is possible, is there a mathematical explanation for why Welch's ANOVA only works for one-way comparisons (I can cope with equations but accompanying words of explanation would be very welcome)?
5. Does anyone recommend an alternative method for comparing treatment group means, where there is a blocking factor and the standard ANOVA assumption of homogeneity of variance between treatment groups is violated?

Comment: Note - please let me know if you think this would be better split into multiple questions. They all follow from me trying to get my head round the same problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on which aspect you want to extend.

Let's start with Welch's 2-sample $t$-test, the simplest case of one-way ANOVA.  Just as Student's $t$-statistic is what you get using a single binary predictor in a standard linear regression, Welch's 2-sample $t$-statistic is what you get using single binary predictor in a standard linear regression but using model-robust 'sandwich' standard errors (at least up to factors like $(n-1)/n$). This is shown by straightforward linear algebra, but it always takes me a while to reconstruct the proof, so I'm not giving it here (perhaps someone will ask a question about it)

So you can extend Welch's 2-sample $t$-test to one-way ANOVA, two-way fixed-effects ANOVA, and general fixed-effects linear regression by doing them as regression. The standard errors are available with `,robust` in Stata and with the `sandwich` package in R. This is a lot easier than finding new ANOVA formulas.

What you don't get this way is an extension of Welch's rules for the $t$-test degrees of freedom (if you're working in a setting where the degrees of freedom are small enough to matter).  On the other hand, the paper given in the linked question doesn't seem to extend those rules, either: it just uses the ordinary residual df. You also don't (as far as I know) get random-effects ANOVA this way.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful. It's pointed me in the direction of some further reading! After that I may try to formulate a question specifically on the maths/algebra, if I don't find it explained elsewhere in the meantime.

Comment: I do often work with data where the degrees of freedom are small enough to matter, so it's useful to know that the Welch's rules for the t-test degrees of freedom are not extended beyond the one-way comparison. Thanks for pointing out that component of Welch's rules as separate from the estimate of the standard error.